# Convert ICU Unicode string to std::wstring (or wchar_t*)

Tags: c++, icu

Is there an icu function to create a `std::wstring` from an icu `UnicodeString` ? I have been searching the ICU manual but haven't been able to find one.

(I know i can convert `UnicodeString` to `UTF8` and then convert to platform dependent `wchar_t*` but i am looking for one function in `UnicodeString` which can do this conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't dictate any specific encoding for `std::wstring`. On Windows systems, `wchar_t` is 16-bit, and on Linux, macOS, and several other platforms, `wchar_t` is 32-bit. As far as C++'s `std::wstring` is concerned, it is just an arbitrary sequence of `wchar_t` in much the same way that `std::string` is just an arbitrary sequence of `char`.

It seems that `icu::UnicodeString` has no in-built way of creating a `std::wstring`, but if you really want to create a `std::wstring` anyway, you can use the C-based API [`u_strToWCS()`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#a184562a078b0a961d9281b0c29bb5406) like this:

```
icu::UnicodeString ustr = /* get from somewhere */;
std::wstring wstr;

int32_t requiredSize;
UErrorCode error = U_ZERO_ERROR;

// obtain the size of string we need
u_strToWCS(nullptr, 0, &requiredSize, ustr.getBuffer(), ustr.length(), &error);

// resize accordingly (this will not include any terminating null character, but it also doesn't need to either)
wstr.resize(requiredSize);

// copy the UnicodeString buffer to the std::wstring.
u_strToWCS(wstr.data(), wstr.size(), nullptr, ustr.getBuffer(), ustr.length(), &error);
```

Supposedly, `u_strToWCS()` will use the most efficient method for converting from `UChar` to `wchar_t` (if they are the same size, then it is just a straightfoward copy I suppose).

Comment: It seems unwise not to zero-terminate `wstr`.  Suppose someone calls `wstr.c_str()`.

Comment: You don't need to zero terminate `std::string` yourself, that will only throw off the `.size()` of it. If someone calls `.c_str()` then a null terminator is added automatically.